# Count numbers of vowels and consonants from a given string

Tags: python

Question is Count numbers of vowels and consonants from a given string.

I did this, why is not working ??????

```
def is_vowel(ch):
    return ch in "AEIOUaeiou"


def count_vowels(s):
    return len([i for i in s if is_vowel(i)])


def count_consonants(s):
    return len([i for i in s if not is_vowel(i) and ('a' <= i <= 'z' or 'A' <= i <= 'Z')])
```

Comment: It works fine for me, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can simply the logic and make the syntax compact as such:

```py
vowels = "AEIOUaeiou"


def count_vowels(word):
    return sum(1 for ch in word if ch in vowels)  # use generator expression.


def count_consonants(s):
    return sum(1 for ch in word if ch not in vowels)


word = 'schoolbus'

print(count_vowels('mississippi'))  #  4

print(count_consonants(word))      #  6
```

Comment: Glad that I can help. Would you be able to ✅ accept this post then?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood your question well, is this something you want..?

```
def count_vowels(s):
    return len([i for i in s if is_vowel(i)])


def count_consonants(s):
    return len([i for i in s if not is_vowel(i) and i.isalpha()])
```

This gives;

```
>>> print(count_consonants('BlackAbdul'))
 7
>>> print(count_vowels('BlackAbdul'))
3
```